# How can I find my 3DS serial number without the tags?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds

I got a 3DS during certain times in 2015, and is currently aging along with me.
Now I never realized this, but my younger sister got ahold of it and tore up the tags on both the box and the system. I want to sign up for Club Nintendo and see if my device is still redeemable there, but this is the only Nintendo handheld device I own.
What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Club Nintendo was discontinued in 2015, so there is currently no way to register the serial number of 3DS consoles.